# Determining the number of real roots of a certain function

Tags: polynomials, roots

I apologize in advance for asking a homework question, but I have genuinely no idea on how to approach part b). The question is as follows:

> (a) Show that the polynomial expression $x^4 -x^2 + x +\frac{5}{4}$ can be written in the form $(x^2-a)^2 + (x-b)^2$
>
> (b) Hence, determine the number of real roots of $y=6x^5 - 10x^3 +15x^2 + 300x +30$

I know how to do part a) and got $(x^2-1)^2+(x+\frac{1}{2})^2=x^4 -x^2 + x +\frac{5}{4}$, but I am unsure of how to do part b) at all. It would be great if in your answer you could explain some of the logic and reasoning behind each step.

Thank you

Comment: Hint. Look at the derivative of the quintic. When you solve the problem you can  post an answer to your own question, and accept it.

Comment: Interesting I get $x^4-x^2+x+10=0$ I'll see what I can do from there, thanks!

Comment: Observe that $$y'(x)= 30 \left (x^4-x^2+x + \frac 5 4 \right ) + 300 - \frac {75} {2} = 30 (x^2-1)^2 + 30 \left (x+\frac 1 2\right )^2 + \frac {525} {2} >0.$$ So $y(x)$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: ok so one root because gradient is always positive, got it thanks

Comment: Exactly one root @sab hoque.

Comment: @dantopa was there something wrong with my question or is this just because I'm a new member

Comment: @sab hoque: Standard welcome for new member. Welcome aboard.

Comment: @Dbchatto67 I have proposed an answer based off your comments see below

Comment: **based on your comment. A grammatical error which makes me feel angry.

Comment: english is not my strong point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interesting observation to make is that when the polynomial is differentiated, a very nice term comes out
$$
\begin{align}
y^\prime &= 30x^4 -30x^2 +30x +300 \\
&=30\left(x^4 -x^2 +x +10\right) \\
&=30\left((x^2-1)^2 +\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 +\frac{35}{4}\right)>0\tag{from part (a)} 
\end{align}
$$
Therefore the function $y=6x^5 - 10x^3 +15x^2 + 300x +30$ is monotonically increasing (strictly increasing) for all $x\in R$. This suggests that the curve is of the sort:
[image]
A curve of this form can only have one root

Comment: You should also mention that a polynomial of odd degree has at least one root by intermediate value theorem. But in this case since the polynomial is strictly increasing so it can have at most one real root. Combining these two arguments it follows that the given polynomial $y(x)$ has exactly one real root.

Comment: @Dbchatto67 I'm not sure what intermediate value theorem is, but I assume it is that $f(-1)<0$ and $f(0)>0$ so there must be a root in between?

Comment: Precisely it is. See here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem